# US Social Security survivor’s benefit—amount

Tags: united-states, social-security

Trying to help a widow plan for the future…

According to “[Survivors Benefit Amount](https://www.ssa.gov/benefits/survivors/ifyou.html#h6)” (as I understand), she should get 100% of her late husband’s benefits and lose her smaller amount.  In a phone interview with the local Social Security office, she was told 82.5%.  But neither computes to the dollar amount she was told by the same person.

**Am I right about the hundred percent, or are there factors that page does not disclose that could reduce it?**

Update: I called the Social Security national line, and to my surprise was not on hold for an hour.  Person told me that I was correct and did not know why the local person got it wrong.  The deceased was 91; the widow is slightly younger.

Comment: Is she at full retirement age?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have made this an answer instead of an update.

I called the Social Security national line, and to my surprise was not on hold for an hour.  Person told me that I was correct and did not know why the local person got it wrong.

Later, when she told me how much she was getting, I added back the Medicare premium and found that it was indeed the amount the husband had been getting.